# HP Pavilion x360 with Realtek wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

Basically, I have a new laptop which needs a new driver. I have an Hp pavilion x360 [Pavilion x360 14-cd0520sa ] with the RealTek Wireless adapter and need the apt' driver for this. Any clues?
I have posted a support request to HP as well, so I'll wait for that answer as well.
Obvioulsy, as I can not get the laptop in question online, I can't post any log files [or at least, I don't know /how/ to post log files] but the issue is simple. Ubuntu 18.04lts [for which I have a bootable USB] just does not see the wireless adapter, so I need a new driver.

This is the manually typed output of the instructions below:

```
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
soft blocked: no
hard blocked: no

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
soft blocked: yes
hard blocked: no
```

Result of Wireless Info Script: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rCQqRStSNw/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88794/discussion-on-question-by-piloti-hp-pavilion-x360-with-realtek-wireless).